# Swift : How to use method in framework in Viewcontroller?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, frameworks, bridge-header

I've import framework in project and create a bridge header since project is in swift.

Now, I want to invoke method `getChallengeDeviceId() present in Common.h header file in CommonLibrary framework.`

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

How can this be done?

Comment: it should be something like this `#import <CommonLibrary/Common.h>`

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 : Still the same. What's difference between "" and <>

Comment: did you try to call it something like .... classname.methodname ???? for eg `Common.getChallengeDeviceId(parameters)`

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 : Yes..tried but Common file dosen't list-up in intellisense drop down list.

Comment: You should use a instance to call  `- (void) getChallengeDeviceId ` method.

Comment: @JayprakashDubey `let common = Common()`
`common.getChallengeDeviceId("iPhone5S")`  like this.

Answer (score 1):

Use OC code in Swift project:

1.Creat a file: `produceName-Bridging-Header.h`

2.Set `targets->build settings ->Object-C Bridging Header` to `produceName-Bridging-Header.h` in building settings.

3.Import .h file in `produceName-Bridging-Header.h`.

For u, `#import <CommonLibrary/Common.h>`

4.U can use the OC class.

In your case, maybe you should use like this:

```
let common = Common()//Or any other init method(Maybe a singleton or somthing)
common.getChallengeDeviceId("iPhone5S")
```

[image]

Comment: getting 2 error : could not build module commonLibrary and Failed to import bridging header. In set 2 it should be productName/produceName-Bridging-Header.h right?

Comment: @JayprakashDubey ProductName is based on your project.After this, you had better clean your project.

Comment: Didn't get..say my project name is ABC-Swift-Library then ABC-Swift-Library/ABC-Swift-Library-Bridge-header.h file should be written in Obj-C Bridging header of Project and Target as well. Right?

Comment: @JayprakashDubey See my screenshot.

Comment: If I could vote more than once!! This should be repeated in PROJECT also right?

Comment: I can not understand what you mean `This`.

Comment: The steps you have shown in screenshot is for TARGETS. It should also be repeated for PROJECT?

Comment: @JayprakashDubey Considering there may be several targets which need different `bridge headers` in one project, i do not set it in  PROJECT.

Answer (score 0):

1 Go to targets->build settings ->Object-C Bridging Header

2. Try this $(SRCROOT)/Productname/Productname-Bridging-Header.h

Comment: This was my third option apart from ProductName/ProductName-Bridging-Header.h and ProductName-Bridging-Header.h

Comment: @JayprakashDubey  ...remove a bridging file from your project and add new bridging file and do deep clean and build